# DoCmd.OutputTo not working in MS Access 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having a bit of trouble with VBA in MS Access 2010.
My code is attempting to create a new report for each unique Settlement No. I'm then exporting that report to a folder that's created with today's date and the PDF file is assigned a name with the Settlement No.

In the code below, I keep getting an error in the line with the DoCmd.OutputTo method.

```
Public Function exporttopdf()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim temp As String

mypath = "S:\Settlement Reports\" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "\"

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT dbs_eff_date, batch_id_r1, jrnl_name, ledger, entity_id_s1, account_s2, intercompany_s6, trans_amt, dbs_description, icb_name, [Settlement No] FROM [Today's Settled Jrnls]", dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rs.EOF

temp = rs("[Settlement No]")
MyFileName = rs("[Settlement No]") & ".PDF"

DoCmd.OpenReport "Settlement Report", acViewReport, , "[Settlement No]='" & temp & "'"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Settlement Report"
rs.MoveNext

Loop

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

If I replace mypath & MyFileName with a hard-coded file path and file name, the macro works so I'm thinking that's where my error is but I can't get it to work correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's the specific error:

> Run-time error '2501': The OutputTo action was canceled.

Comment: What is the value for `rs("[Settlement No]") `?

Comment: @braX It should be text so in this instance it's "ICB031-01232018"

Comment: *Should be*? Add this right before it then check your immediate window. `Debug.Print mypath & MyFileName`

Comment: @brax Looks like it worked. The result I get is "S:\Settlement Reports\01-23-2018\ICB031-01222018.PDF". I'm wondering if it's not working because the "01-23-18" folder isn't created yet. Do I need another command to create that folder in my code?

Comment: Yes, the folder has to exist. Use `MkDir mypath`

Comment: @Parfait Edited.

Comment: @braX It worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to check to make sure the folder exists first, and create it if it doesn't exist. Like this:

```
If Dir(mypath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir mypath
```